# Armature on multiple instanced meshes working incorrectly

Tags: armature

I am trying to create a simple low-poly human hair factory. My idea is this:

- I create a strand of hair - just a simple textured mesh strip.
- I create multiple instances of the strand to form the hair, so that I can edit the original strand and the whole hair will be modified accoordingly.
- I create an armature to shape the hair.

So I now have an armature affecting multiple instanced strands of hair. I came into this problem: the armature is deforming the strands incorrectly in some places:

[image]

Weights for the vertices are set in the original strand. I only set different vertex groups for each instance, which can be done (as seen in the screenshot, at the left).

As can be seen, the hair is deformed correctly at the sides, but incorrectly in the back (the hair should obviously be closed, but it goes in the opposite direction, i.e. "outwards"). What can cause this? Can it be the fact that the instaced strands are translated and rotated? How can I fix this?